# Direct link to Facebook Page's "post by others" (now renamed to "Posts to page")

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

Before the last redesign of Facebook Pages I could use a link like `https://www.facebook.com/pages/pagename/pageid?filter=2` to go directly to a view where I saw only the posts on the page by people liking the page. That is, it excluded posts by administrators (the third option was to view "Highlights" IIRC, that is, a mix of posts by users and administrators).

After the last redesign, Facebook changed all this. Now I have to go to the page and then scroll down a bit and click `Post to page`. The link I click (#) is not possible to use directly. Anyone know if it is possible to link directly to a view showing the "likers" posts?

The reason I want this is that I admin a page where my admin posts are uninteresting for the users. People like this page to see other non-admins posts. It is a mess to give the users instructions for how to find what they are looking for. Instead I want to give them the direct link.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds you should be using Facebook Groups. Also your admin users should post as the page to prevent confusion. If the main point is for users to talk to users, Facebook groups is the way to proceed.

Comment: You are probably right, but now I have 1500 users and if I switch format I would be happy if 150 of them bothered to follow. It is not really an option.